# Hide tab size in status bar Sublime Text

Tags: ide, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

How to hide/remove from status bar information about Tab Size in Sublime Text?

[image]

**UPDATE:** 
I am searching command like this two, but to hide Tab Size information (like in screenshot)

```
"show_encoding": false
"show_line_endings": false
```

Is there something like `"show_tab_size: false"` etc? Or may be I can realize this with custom plugin?

Comment: What wasn't clear? He wants to prevent the tab/space indentation field from being displayed on the Sublime Text status bar - wasn't his question's subject line alone enough to convey that? seanser's first language is obviously not English, but what he was asking seemed clear enough to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't hide the tab/space indentation field on the Sublime Text status bar.

Strange because you can hide the file encoding and line endings with these settings:

```
"show_encoding": false,
"show_line_endings": false,
```

If you want you can instead hide the whole status bar; from the menu with: `Menu --> View --> Hide Status Bar`.

Or you could set keys with this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+whatever"], "command": "toggle_status_bar" }
```

It does not appear to be possible to hide the tab/space indentation field on the status bar by using either a plugin or theme.

Comment: what about ST API? Is there some functions that I can use in my custom plugin to hide this information?

Comment: You can set a new value to display on the status bar using `set_status()` and remove that item with `erase_status()` but I can't see any way of removing the tab/space indentation field. I looked through the undocumented API too. I'm not sure what can be controlled by a theme, but I've just searched the `Default.sublime-theme` and it looks like all you can do is change the margins, colours, and opacity of the whole status bar and not what is displayed on it. I suggest [you add a feature request](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core) for `"show_indentation"` and hope the setting gets added.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to achieve this if you don't mind losing the file type too.

Find the `.sublime-theme` of the UI you're using and look for the code below, setting it to `-240` did it for me but depending on your theme you might have to play around with the number to get it right for you.

`"class": "status_bar",
      "content_margin": [-2, -2, -240, 3],`

Result

[image]